# Как обойти строку в lua

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

вопрос, возможно, тривиальный, но все же. Есть строкa:

`string1 = '{"secret1":"one","secret2":"two","secret3":"three"}'`

и таблица

`string2 = {"secret"}`

Следующим циклом я проверяю вхождение елемента таблицы string2 в строке string1 и регуляркой заменяю каждое вхождение.

```
string1 = '{"secret1":"one","secret2":"two","secret3":"three"}'
string2 = {"secret"}
for i, val in pairs(string2) do
    for word in string1:gmatch'([^:{},""]+)' do
      if word:find(val) then
          i = word
          string1 = string1:gsub("\x22-." .. val .. ".-\x22:.-,-(.\x22)", "\x22" .. i .. "\x22:\x22some_number\x22")
      end
    end
end
print(string1)
```

Результат получается такой:

```
{"secret3":"some_number","secret3":"some_number","secret3":"some_number"}
```

Как добиться замены уникальных значений, чтобы результат был:

```
{"secret1":"some_number","secret2":"some_number","secret3":"some_number"}
```

Comment: Как это у вас такой результат получился? У меня [вот что ваш код выдает](https://ideone.com/DUcQHH).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `string1 = '{"secret1":"one","secret2":"two","secret3":"three"}'
string2 = {"secret"}
for i, val in pairs(string2) do
    for word in string1:gmatch'([^:{},""]+)' do
      if word:find(val) then
          i = word
          string1 = string1:gsub("\x22-." .. val .. ".-\x22:.-,-(.\x22)", "\x22" .. i .. "\x22:\x22some_number\x22")
      end
    end
end
print(string1)`

Comment: `for i, val in pairs(string2) do
    string1 = string1:gsub("(\"[^\"]*" .. val .. "[^\"]*\":\")[^\"]*", "%1some_number\"")
end`? См. https://ideone.com/2j1fqp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `string1:gsub` без предварительного поиска ключей:

```
string1 = '{"secret1":"one","secret2":"two","secret3":"three"}'
string2 = {"secret"}
for i, val in pairs(string2) do
    string1 = string1:gsub("(\"[^\"]*" .. val .. "[^\"]*\":\")[^\"]*", "%1some_number")
end
print(string1)
--{"secret1":"some_number","secret2":"some_number","secret3":"some_number"}
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/2j1fqp)

**Подробности**

- `("[^"]*secret[^"]*":")` - Подмаска №1: `"`, 0 и более символов, отличных от `"`, затем `secret`, снова 0 и более символов, отличных от `"`, и затем `":"`
- `[^"]*"` - 0 и более символов, отличных от `"` и затем `"`.

Шаблон замены - `"%1some_number"` - подставляет значение подмаски №1 и добавляет `some_number`.

Comment: ради инетреса - почему шаблон замены не переписываеться каждый проход цикла как в моем варианте?

Comment: Потому что `gsub` находит и заменяет все непересекающиеся вхождения шаблона. Поиск следующего совпадения осуществляется после предыдущего. Так как у вас цикл, а шаблон находит все ключи, содержащие `secret`, все они были заменены.

Comment: перефразирую - в вашем варианте все работает как нужно - в моем каждый цикл подставлялась новое значение которое заменяло все вхождения

Comment: не могли бы обяснить тоже самое только для строк без кавычек - `string1 = '{secret1:one,secret2:two,secret3:three}' `

Comment: @RizakFamily Вот [такой вариант](https://ideone.com/tZHs5o) может подойти.